# Two seemingly identical functions produce different results

Tags: common-lisp

The function

```
(defun test-1 ()
  (format t "~%Enter number less or equal 1: ")
  (let ((x (read)))
    (when (> x 1)
      (format t "~%Error!")
      (test-1))
    x))
```

evaluates to 2 when 2 followed by 1 is entered, while the function

```
(defun test-2 ()
  (format t "~%Enter number less or equal 1: ")
  (let ((x (read)))
    (cond ((> x 1)
           (format t "~%Error!")
           (test-2))
          (t x))))
```

evaluates to 1 when 2 followed by 1 is entered, which is expected. I don't understand why test-1 behaves differently.

Comment: Note that you also need to call `(finish-output)` after printing and before reading. Output can be buffered in Common Lisp. Make sure that output has reached the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test-1, every time that a number >1 is entered, the function is called recursively and the call is placed in the stack. When finally a value <= 1 is entered it returns x. But note that the return value x is outside the when function, so the value of the calling function replaces the value of the called function. Therefore the result is the first value that you entered.
In test-2 on the other hand, when a value <= 1 is entered, it calls the function recursively and the returned value is not replaced by any other value, but it's passed to the calling function. Therefore it returns the first entered value which is <= 1.

Comment: "But note that the return value x is outside the when function ..." That explains it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is not tail-recursive, while the second version is. The first version will return the value read from `*standard-input*` by the very first call to `read` made. The second will answer the value produced by the last call to `read`. Try [`trace`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/m_tracec.htm#trace) to understand the difference in behaviour.

The `let` form used in the first version has the basic shape

```lisp
(let (...)
   (when ... (test-1))
   x). ;; <--- This is the expression that determines the result in the first variant
```

The `let` body acts as an implicit `progn` here, i.e., since there are forms after the `when` in the body, the `when` is executed for it's side-effects, but its result is not used.

To make the first version tail-recursive, do it with something like

```lisp
(defun test-1 ()
  (format t "~%Enter number less or equal 1: ")
  (let ((x (read)))
    (if (> x 1)
      (progn
        (format t "~%Error!")
        (test-1))
      x))
```